# New property in class?

Tags: vb.net, lidgren

Well, my question is simple.

I want to add a property to a pre - defined class.

```
Imports Lidgren.Network

Module Socket
    Public Clients As List(Of NetConnection) = New List(Of NetConnection)
```

Need to add the "index " property , so that it is " Clients (sender ) .Index "

Comment: by "predefined" do you mean something like a 3rd party Type which is compiled into a DLL perhaps?

Comment: Yep. I want do add a property do a compiled dll.

Comment: That's not a property, it's a field. - And your "class" is a module.

Comment: you *could* subclass the Type to add the property, but @oneFineDay is correct, you probably just need the index from the List

Answer (score 1):

Your using a `List(Of T)` so you have access to it's [IndexOf method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) - it returns the zero-based position in the collection.

```
Dim i As Integer = Clients.IndexOf(sender)
```